# Controller fails to be called

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I have recently started learning ember.js and for some reason i cant get my controller to be called

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('about');
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'pie','koala'];
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    sortedModel : function(){
        alert("this works");
    }
});
```

app.js

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    <ul>
    {{#each sortedModel as |item|}}
      <li>{{item}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>
```

i try calling it by referancing sortedModel in the loop, as per tutorial
its probably something really stupid but for the life of me i cant seem to see it, i followed the tutorial to the letter and cant continue without it

Comment: I had the same problem with one of the tutorials, I couldn't find the answer, I just resolved to using another tutorial

Comment: Could you point out which tutorial ?..you are iterating `sortedModel` function in template

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Mark the function with .property()

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    sortedModelAlertOnly : function(){
        alert("this works");
    }.property(),
    sortedModel : function(){
       return this.get('model').sort();
    }.property('model')
});
```

http://jsbin.com/beguqoqubi/edit?html,js,output